# Fonts no recognized by Imagemagick after update

Tags: ubuntu, imagemagick

After an update of Imagemagick in Ubuntu 22.04, none of the fonts in the type-ghostscript.xml file is recognized (not listed in the **convert -list font** command).

The type-ghostscript.xml file is included in the /etc/ImageMagick-6/type.xml file, and the fonts files exists.
I ran the imagick_type_gen scripts as shown in [Make ImageMagick recognize a font](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2650882/make-imagemagick-recognize-a-font#comment2674052_2651840) but fonts like Helvetica are not listed.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some ways to help work out what is going wrong. First, you can check your **ImageMagick** version, and whether you have `fontconfig`, `gslib` (Ghostscript) and `freetype` delegates built into your version:

```
identify -version

Version: ImageMagick 7.1.1-3 Q16-HDRI aarch64 20959 https://imagemagick.org
Copyright: (C) 1999 ImageMagick Studio LLC
License: https://imagemagick.org/script/license.php
Features: Cipher DPC HDRI Modules OpenMP(5.0) 
Delegates (built-in): bzlib fontconfig freetype gslib heic jng jp2 jpeg jxl lcms lqr ltdl lzma openexr png ps raw tiff webp xml zlib
```

---

Then you can check your `CONFIGURE_PATH` to see where **ImageMagick** is looking for its confguration files such as `type.xml`, `delegates.xml` and `policy.xml`:

```
identify -list configure | grep CONFIGURE_PATH

CONFIGURE_PATH        /opt/homebrew/Cellar/imagemagick/7.1.1-3/etc/ImageMagick-7/
```

---

Then you can examine those files:

```
more /opt/homebrew/Cellar/imagemagick/7.1.1-3/etc/ImageMagick-7/type-ghostscript.xml
```

---

Then you can run your `identify -list font` command again with debugging turned on in order to see what **ImageMagick** looks at, what it finds and what it understands:

```
identify -debug all -list font 2>&1 | more  

2023-03-26T10:43:03+00:00 0:00.001 0.000u 7.1.1 Configure identify[20272]: utility.c/ExpandFilenames/975/Configure
  Command line: identify {-debug} {all} {-list} {font}
2023-03-26T10:43:03+00:00 0:00.001 0.000u 7.1.1 Configure identify[20272]: configure.c/GetConfigureOptions/695/Configure
  Searching for configure file: "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/imagemagick/7.1.1-3/share/ImageMagick-7/type.xml"
2023-03-26T10:43:03+00:00 0:00.001 0.000u 7.1.1 Configure identify[20272]: configure.c/GetConfigureOptions/695/Configure
  Searching for configure file: "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/imagemagick/7.1.1-3/lib/ImageMagick//config-Q16HDRI/type.xml"
2023-03-26T10:43:03+00:00 0:00.001 0.000u 7.1.1 Configure identify[20272]: configure.c/GetConfigureOptions/695/Configure
  Searching for configure file: "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/imagemagick/7.1.1-3/etc/ImageMagick-7/type.xml"
2023-03-26T10:43:03+00:00 0:00.001 0.010u 7.1.1 Configure identify[20272]: configure.c/GetConfigureOptions/695/Configure
  Searching for configure file: "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/imagemagick/7.1.1-3/share/doc/ImageMagick-7/type.xml"
2023-03-26T10:43:03+00:00 0:00.001 0.010u 7.1.1 Configure identify[20272]: configure.c/GetConfigureOptions/695/Configure
  Searching for configure file: "/Users/mark/.config/ImageMagick/type.xml"
2023-03-26T10:43:03+00:00 0:00.001 0.010u 7.1.1 Configure identify[20272]: type.c/LoadTypeCache/1098/Configure
  Loading type configure file "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/imagemagick/7.1.1-3/etc/ImageMagick-7/type.xml" ...
2023-03-26T10:43:03+00:00 0:00.001 0.010u 7.1.1 Policy identify[20272]: policy.c/IsRightsAuthorized/647/Policy
  Domain: Path; rights=Read; pattern="/opt/homebrew/Cellar/imagemagick/7.1.1-3/etc/ImageMagick-7/type-ghostscript.xml" ...
2023-03-26T10:43:03+00:00 0:00.001 0.010u 7.1.1 Configure identify[20272]: type.c/LoadTypeCache/1098/Configure
  Loading type configure file "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/imagemagick/7.1.1-3/etc/ImageMagick-7/type-ghostscript.xml" ...

Path: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/imagemagick/7.1.1-3/etc/ImageMagick-7/type-ghostscript.xml
  Font: AvantGarde-Book
    family: AvantGarde
    style: Normal
    stretch: Normal
    weight: 400
    glyphs: /opt/homebrew/share/ghostscript/fonts/a010013l.pfb
  Font: AvantGarde-BookOblique
    family: AvantGarde
    style: Oblique
    stretch: Normal
    weight: 400
    glyphs: /opt/homebrew/share/ghostscript/fonts/a010033l.pfb
```